# how to compare between two images different in detail (low & high) concerning isopreference curves with images i(u,v)?

Tags: image-processing

Regarding to these images , given the image I(u,v) formulate an equation which may be considered as
a detail measurement of an image. This measurement should give a relatively low value for a low
detailed image (as given in left-hand side) whereas it should give higher values for a high detailed
image (as given in right-hand side).** Please use mathematical expressions as much as possible.**

[image]

Comment: what specific issue do you have with your homework? have you talked to the teacher?